# How to get code below to work on 2.5 million rows without blowing up

Tags: r, data.table

I tried running this code on 2.5 million row and my computer blew up...  The code works but is slow on large datasets.  The code, input and output are below.
I original get the solution from my first post which had a missing piece in the logic which added in the code below.
Can someone suggest an improvement?

## Thanks for any help I get!

```
    df <- read.table(header=T,text='DATE    ID
    DATE    ID
12/31/2009  1
12/31/2010  1
12/31/2011  1
12/31/2012  1
12/31/2013  1
12/31/2011  2
12/31/2011  2
12/31/2012  2
12/31/2012  2
12/31/2013  2
12/31/2013  2
12/31/2008  3
12/31/2009  3
12/31/2009  3
12/31/2009  3
12/31/2010  3
12/31/2010  3
12/31/2010  3
12/31/2011  3
12/31/2011  3
12/31/2012  3
12/31/2008  4
12/31/2008  4
12/31/2009  4
12/31/2009  4
12/31/2010  4
12/31/2010  4
12/31/2011  4
12/31/2011  4
12/31/2011  4
12/31/2011  4
12/31/2011  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2012  5
12/31/2009  5
12/31/2010  5
12/31/2011  5
12/31/2011  5
12/31/2012  5
12/31/2012  5
12/31/2013  5')
df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE,"%m/%d/%Y")
split.rows <- split.default(1:nrow(df),trim(df$ID),drop=T)

lapply(split.rows,function(x){
split_df <- df[x,]

group <- vector('integer',length(x))
group_date <- vector('character',length(x))

group[1] <- 1
group_date[1] <- as.character(split_df[1,'DATE'])

for (i in 2:nrow(split_df)){
if (split_df[i,'DATE'] - split_df[i-1,'DATE'] > 365 || split_df[i,'DATE'] - as.Date(group_date[i-1])> 365){
group[i] <- group[i - 1] + 1
group_date[i] <- as.character(split_df[i,'DATE'])
  }
else{
group[i] <- group[i - 1]
group_date[i] <- group_date[i-1]
  }
}

df$GROUP[x] <<- group
df$GROUPDATE[x] <<- group_date

return(NULL)
})

df[,]

=================
Input:
DATE    ID
12/31/2009  1
12/31/2010  1
12/31/2011  1
12/31/2012  1
12/31/2013  1
12/31/2011  2
12/31/2011  2
12/31/2012  2
12/31/2012  2
12/31/2013  2
12/31/2013  2
12/31/2008  3
12/31/2009  3
12/31/2009  3
12/31/2009  3
12/31/2010  3
12/31/2010  3
12/31/2010  3
12/31/2011  3
12/31/2011  3
12/31/2012  3
12/31/2008  4
12/31/2008  4
12/31/2009  4
12/31/2009  4
12/31/2010  4
12/31/2010  4
12/31/2011  4
12/31/2011  4
12/31/2011  4
12/31/2011  4
12/31/2011  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2012  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2013  4
12/31/2012  5
12/31/2009  5
12/31/2010  5
12/31/2011  5
12/31/2011  5
12/31/2012  5
12/31/2012  5
12/31/2013  5


output
DATE    ID  group   groupdate
12/31/2009  1   1   31-Dec-09
12/31/2010  1   1   31-Dec-09
12/31/2011  1   2   31-Dec-11
12/31/2012  1   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  1   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2011  2   1   31-Dec-11
12/31/2011  2   1   31-Dec-11
12/31/2012  2   2   31-Dec-12
12/31/2012  2   2   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  2   2   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  2   2   31-Dec-12
12/31/2008  3   1   31-Dec-08
12/31/2009  3   1   31-Dec-08
12/31/2009  3   1   31-Dec-08
12/31/2009  3   1   31-Dec-08
12/31/2010  3   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2010  3   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2010  3   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2011  3   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2011  3   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2012  3   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2008  4   1   31-Dec-08
12/31/2008  4   1   31-Dec-08
12/31/2009  4   1   31-Dec-08
12/31/2009  4   1   31-Dec-08
12/31/2010  4   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2010  4   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2011  4   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2011  4   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2011  4   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2011  4   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2011  4   2   31-Dec-10
12/31/2012  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2012  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2012  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2012  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2012  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2012  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  4   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2012  5   1   31-Dec-12
12/31/2009  5   1   31-Dec-09
12/31/2010  5   1   31-Dec-09
12/31/2011  5   2   31-Dec-11
12/31/2011  5   2   31-Dec-11
12/31/2012  5   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2012  5   3   31-Dec-12
12/31/2013  5   3   31-Dec-12
```

Comment: Use `data.table`, not `data.frame`. It will use faster `split` method. Use `:=` instead of `<-` on columns. In general read [data.table getting started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) page. When asking question try to use minimal required example, so it can be also visually compared, when possible.

Comment: For data.table, I also like using this cheat sheet: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf